# App Transport Security blocked

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to enable the connection for some hardware domain , and i get that new iOS9 security message .

I have enabled the domain `http://192.168.4.1` in the `info.plist`, and still i get this message .

My plist is :

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>http://192.168.4.1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: are you sure that IP address is a domain? What about adding mapping IP into domain name in /etc/hosts

Comment: what do you mean "a domain" ? the iPhone used to send messages to this ip before ...

Comment: NSExceptionDomains -> Domain. Domain is not IP but a DNS name

Comment: I dont think there is a difference, ip/name are the same. moreover you dont always have a domain name. this is an hardware device we have developed. it has an ip only .

Comment: So you have to use different info plist key for IP address (which doesn't exists). It's not the same. I have already wrote how to solve it in first comment but you are ignorant

Comment: I am not sure how clear to me your first comment . Anyway , enabling all of them works-NSAllowsArbitraryLoads , but its not good .

Comment: That info plist doesn't work with IP addresses. If you want it to work with that key you have to use domain name or find another key. If the key doesn't exists it means you have to submit to Apple feature request

Comment: @MarekH so what do you do ? wait for some day that they will add it ? right now, lots of IoT hardware devices that have an ip address, no ssl , where iPhone has to connect with them . whats the solution here ? right now i am not getting any responds no more...

Comment: As other suggested disabled all connections and ask for exception (apple review if they reject you). If this doesn't help request a technical support from apple. You might fill a bug report as well that ATS doesn't work with IP

Comment: Here is one resource which might be helpful (Diagnosing Connection Issues) https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/ Also don't worry too much about disabling the whole ATS: https://www.dzombak.com/blog/2015/09/Nobody-is-using-App-Transport-Security--what-s-next-.html

Answer (score 0):

Add all key in info.plist...  & run....it may me helped...

[image]